# What's the correct datetime format for the specified date string?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following date string: `2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621898Z`

For the life of me I can't figure out the format. The closest `datetime` format string that would make sense to me is:

`%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`

I've searched StackOverflow, Google and the Python docs.

Comment: What happens if you use the "closest" format? What's the result and how does it not match your expectations? Which time zone are you living in / which timezone does your PC have?

Answer (score 2):

For such issues, it is worthy to look at `datetime` module and it's `parser.parse` function, which parses any datetime string without you needing to provide the format!

```
from dateutil import parser

dt_obj = parser.parse('2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621898Z')
print(dt_obj)
```

Also the closest format which fits your requirement is `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'` which works with `2019-05-12T14:52:13.136621Z` where '.%f` encapsulates microseconds with 6 decimal places but since your decimal has 9 decimal places, this won't work for you!

Comment: Thank you, however it is the format string I am looking for! Not just parsing the date.

Answer (score 0):

The format is called "round trip format" and Python does not have a format specifier for it, while e.g. .NET has the [`o` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip). Therefore it might be a bit harder to craft a format string:

- In your case it has 9 digits for sub-seconds. @Devesh said it should be 8 digits and the .NET framework uses 7 digits for it. But generally, `%f` should be ok.
- You can't use a hard coded `Z` at the end, because that's the time zone. `Z` would only work for UTC, but would ignore all other time zones. The time zone format specifier is `%z`

As [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) says:

> utcoffset() is transformed into a string of the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]], where HH is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset hours, MM is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset minutes, SS is a 2-digit string giving the number of UTC offset seconds and ffffff is a 6-digit string giving the number of UTC offset microseconds. The ffffff part is omitted when the offset is a whole number of seconds and both the ffffff and the SS part is omitted when the offset is a whole number of minutes. For example, if utcoffset() returns timedelta(hours=-3, minutes=-30), %z is replaced with the string '-0330'

and

> For example, '+01:00:00' will be parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'